# Why does this int32 casting work in Powershell 7 Terminal Window, but not in the actual code?

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm using VS Code (in Powershell ISE mode) with Powershell 7. I'm looping round a load of files and storing each BaseName before processing it. Basenames are all integers e.g. 36543.

```
$TileName = $_.BaseName # Shows in Variables pane as System.Management.Automation.PSObject, value shows 39669
```

I then want the next two values so do:

```
$TileNamePlus1 = [uint32]$TileName+1
$TileNamePlus2 = [uint32]$TileName+2
```

When I hover over these in the Variables pane, they show "396691" and "396692" respectively. But if I type this into the Terminal window in debug mode

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator> $TileNamePlus1

396691
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\Administrator> [uint32]$TileName+1

39670
```

How on earth, can I get the value 39670 into $TileNamePlus1 ? I'm finding PowerShell too permissive, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it just seems to skip over erroneous code rather than produce an error message so I can actually fix things.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Variables pane, the cast operation will take precedence over `+`  at runtime. Do you get an unexpected result when you actually execute the code?

Comment: Hmm good spot. Well I cut and pasted the code into the old ISE, and it seems to work! So the moral or the story here would appear to be, don't use the latest dev tools recommended by MS as they're still buggy. Use old Windows Powershell and the ISE and things will work as expected!